# Vuex sync : Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, synchronization, vuex

Im trying to use vuex to make things easier, overall it's fine, but Im stuck when using a getter with param from an other getter.

main code :

```
<template>
    <v-container>

        <v-card v-for="(order,i) in getOrders" :key="i" class="cart-cards text-left">

                <v-card-title>
                    {{getMealById(order.meal_id).name}}
                </v-card-title>
                <v-btn v-on:click="addQuantity(order)">
                        +
                    </v-btn>
                    <h1>
                        {{order.quantity}}
                    </h1>
                    <v-btn @click="reduceQuantity(order)">
                        -
                    </v-btn>

        </v-card>

    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
    data: () => ({
    }),
    created() {
        this.fetchOrders();
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["fetchOrders"]),
        addQuantity(order) {
            order.quantity += 1;
            this.updateOrders(order);
        },
        reduceQuantity(order) {
            if (order.quantity > 0) {
                order.quantity -= 1;
                this.updateOrders(order);
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["getOrders", "getMealById"]),
    },
};
```

order.js :

```
import axios from 'axios'
import url from '../../config.js'

const state = {
    all_orders: [],
}
const getters = {
    getOrders : (state)=>state.all_orders,

}
const actions = {
    async fetchOrders({commit}) {
        const response = await axios.get("http://" + url + "/orders")
        commit('setOrders',response.data)
    },
    async updateOrders({commit},payload) {
        const response = await axios.put("http://" + url + "/orders/"+payload.id,payload)
        commit('setOrders',response.data)
    },
}
const mutations = {
    setOrders: (state,orders)=>{
        state.all_orders = orders
    },
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

meal.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import url from '../../config.js'

const state = {
    all_meals: [],
}
const getters = {
    getMeals: (state) => state.all_meals,
    getMealById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.all_meals.find(todo => todo.id === id)
    }

}
const actions = {
    async fetchMeals({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get("http://" + url + "/meals")
        commit('setMeals', response.data)
    },
}
const mutations = {
    setMeals: (state, meals) => {
        state.all_meals = meals
    },
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

So when iam accessing the vue from a link, no error, but when I load the url by itself, an error occur and the getMealById dont trigger [image]

overall Is their a good practice for "waiting" for response on state/actions call ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

In component, you can check if `getMeals` returns a non-empty array, then render the `v-for` loop:

```
<template>
<v-container v-if="getMeals().length > 0">

    <v-card v-for="(order,i) in getOrders" :key="i" class="cart-cards text-left">

            <v-card-title>
                {{getMealById(order.meal_id).name}}
            </v-card-title>

    </v-card>

</v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
    data: () => ({
    }),
    created() {
        this.fetchOrders();
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["fetchOrders"]),
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["getMeals", "getOrders", "getMealById"]),
    },
};
```

Comment: Hello ! "getMeals" are not really involved in this page, i tried to v-if on getOrders instead, but it dosn't really work, the issue is that the ```getMealById(order.meal_id).name``` shows up before ```order``` is loaded

Comment: Look carefully at the error. It states that it cannot read the property `name` of undefined (`meal.name`). the `order` is defined (otherwise it wouldn't loop over them), but the meal, the id of which is defined in order (`order.meal_id`) is not yet in the store, thus `getMealById` returns `undefined` and rise the error.

Comment: first of all , sorry i think i edited your response by accident, i wanted to edit my main message. 
Ok, i solved it by adding in ```fetchMeals``` in created, thus i added 2 functions to update the quantity ```addQuantity , reduceQuantity``` and the first call works fine, but after the first one , same error ```Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"```